# How to fit AR process (with nonconsecutive lags) to Time Series?

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

I want to estimate the coefficients for an AR process based on weekly data where the lags occur at t-1, t-52, and t-53. I will naturally lose a year of data to do this.

I currently tried:

```
lags <- rep(0,54)
lags[1]<- NA
lags[52] <- NA
lags[53] <- NA
testResults <- arima(data,order=c(53,0,0),fixed=lags)
```

Basically I tried using an ARIMA and shutting off the MA/differencing. I used 0's for the terms I wanted to exclude (plus intercept, and NAs for the terms I wanted.

I get the following error:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian =TRUE,  : 
non-finite finite-difference value [1]
In addition: Warning message:
In arima(data, order = c(53, 0, 0), fixed = lags) :
some AR parameters were fixed: setting transform.pars = FALSE
```

I'm hoping there is an easier method or potential solution to this error. I want to avoid creating columns with the lagged variables and simply running a regression. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a data-related issue. I managed to replicate the error with simulated data and the following things helped in that particular case: 1) setting SSinit = "Rossignol2011", 2) setting method = "CSS". Maybe setting optim.method = "SANN" also helps, but the estimation was taking forever and I stopped it. Note, however, that the estimates might differ with 1) and 2) modifications. Do they help in your case?

Comment: Thanks @Julius ! Using CSS worked. I realized that I'm interested in a multiplicative ARIMA model where my coefficients for the three lagged terms are phi1, phi2, and phi1*phi2. Any idea if there are any built-in functions or packages to handle this task?

Comment: I am not aware of such package, but since you are interested only in AR part, I suggest that you implement this procedure yourself: after defining the lagged variables use `nls` function to impose the constraint.

Comment: Good to know @Julius , I found the 'sarima' function which allows me to specify the 52-week lag --> sarima(data,1,0,0,1,0,0,52)